# Implementing a templated Array class

Tags: c++, beginner, array, template

I have implemented an Array class using templates. I have used a std::allocator object for memory allocation. Will it be better to use operator new along with placement new for memory allocation?

array.h

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T> class Array;

template<typename T> void swap(Array<T> &first, Array<T> &second);

template <typename T> class Array {
    friend void swap <> (Array<T> &first, Array<T> &second);
public:
    typedef T *iterator;
    typedef const T *const_iterator;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;

    explicit Array(size_type size, const T& value = T());
    Array(const_iterator range_begin, const_iterator range_end);
    Array(const Array&);

    Array& operator=(const Array);

    size_type size() const;

    T& operator[](size_type i);
    const T& operator[](size_type i) const;

    iterator begin();
    const_iterator begin() const;

    iterator end();
    const_iterator end() const;

    ~Array();
private:
    iterator data; // points to the first element of the array
    iterator limit; // points to one past the last element
    iterator avail; // points to one past the allocated memory

    std::allocator<T> alloc; // for memory allocation
};

// implementation
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T> void swap(Array<T> &first, Array<T> &second)
{
    using std::swap;

    swap(first.data, second.data);
    swap(first.limit, second.limit);
    swap(first.avail, second.avail);
}

template<typename T> Array<T>::Array(size_type size, const T& value):
    data(alloc.allocate(size)), limit(data), avail(data + size)
{
    while (limit < data + size)
        alloc.construct(limit++, value);
}

template<typename T> Array<T>::Array(const_iterator range_begin,
        const_iterator range_end):
    data(alloc.allocate(range_end - range_begin)), limit(data),
    avail(data + range_end - range_begin)
{
    const_iterator it = range_begin;
    while (limit < data + range_end - range_begin) {
        alloc.construct(limit++, *it);
        ++it;
    }
}

template<typename T> Array<T>::Array(const Array &original):
    data(alloc.construct(original.size())), limit(data),
    avail(data + original.size)
{
    iterator it = original.begin();
    while (it != original.limit()) {
        alloc.construct(limit++, *it);
        ++it;
    }
}

template<typename T> Array<T>& Array<T>::operator=(const Array rhs)
{
    swap(*this, rhs);

    return *this;
}

template<typename T> typename Array<T>::size_type Array<T>::size() const
{
    return limit - data;
}

template<typename T> T& Array<T>::operator[](size_type i)
{
    return data[i];
}

template<typename T> const T& Array<T>::operator[](size_type i) const
{
    return data[i];
}

template<typename T> typename Array<T>::iterator Array<T>::begin()
{
    return data;
}

template<typename T> typename Array<T>::const_iterator Array<T>::begin() const
{
    return data;
}

template<typename T> typename Array<T>::iterator Array<T>::end()
{
    return limit;
}

template<typename T> typename Array<T>::const_iterator Array<T>::end() const
{
    return limit;
}

template<typename T> Array<T>::~Array()
{
    while (limit != data)
        alloc.destroy(--limit);

    alloc.deallocate(data, avail - data);
}
#endif
```

Comment: I think we'll need to know more about your intent before we can meaningfully answer questions like: "Will it be better to use operator new along with placement new for memory allocation?"